# Javascript 'this' operator

Tags: javascript, this, window-object

I'm struggling to understand why the output of this command is not 10.

```
var x = 10;
console.log(this.x);
```

On the other hand, when x is global the output is indeed 10.

```
x = 10;
console.log(this.x);
```

how come in the first example it does'nt print '10'? x is a variable of "window" object, so 'this' should be window. what am i missing here?

Comment: Where *exactly* in your JavaScript code does that first sample exist? Is it inside of a function?

Comment: This is just a variable, not a const/variable within a scope (function, class etc.). So instead of using `console.log(this.x)` use `console.log(x)`

Comment: Apparently, `var x` in your first example is *not* a global `window` property. Why that is, we can't answer without more context. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Pointy - No. It's the first line of code.

Comment: If you're running this in a browser, and the first line of code really is `var x = 10;` followed by the `console.log()` call, then it would behave the same way as the second snippet. Are you using jsfiddle? If so make sure your JavaScript panel is configured properly because by default it puts the code in a window "load" handler.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks! the problem was I was using jsfiddle!